# Can we use Snowpark to read data from Snowflake and then send it to an external api to load into an application

Tags: api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external

Can we use Snowpark to read data from Snowflake and then send it to an external api to load into an application.

I could see that we can read the data in Snowpark but can we call an url and send the data to the other api connection. I am trying to pass the data to the application endpoint directly on a schedule so we do not need a server running code and pulling data from Snowflake and pushing to the external application.

Comment: Do you mean like sending an HTTP POST to an external URL? If that's the case Snowpark is built on Scala so you can use a Scala lib to send an POST, I don't see why you would not be able to.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu, I am still awaiting a license for me but just wanted all of your expert opinion. I was facing a weird error so mostly might be for my access. I will get back on this thread when I am able to get some further on the POC. 

Thanks again for your thoughts.